# unable to display images from model usingo django

Tags: python, django, imagefield

in settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'pictures')
MEDIA_URL = '/pictures/'
```

in models.py

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # this is many to one relationship, on_deleting user, profile will also be deleted
    campaign_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    campaign_image = models.ImageField(default="default_campaign.png",upload_to="campaign_pictures")
```

in views.py

```
def landing_page(request):
    campaigns = Campaign.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    print(campaigns)
    return render(request, 'core/landing_page.html',{'campaigns':campaigns})
```

in landing_page.html

```
{% for campaign in campaigns %}
<img src="{{campaign.campaign_image.url}}">
{% endfor %}
```

**issue**

1. if file name is abc xyz.jpg, it gets saved into /pictures/campaign_pictures as abc_xyz.jpg
2. in html template, the src of image should be '/pictures/campaign_pictures/abc_xyz.jpg' but it shows only '/pictures/abc%20xyz.jpg'

Comment: Possibly you are uploading an image with a name having space.

Comment: @SarojRai : yes, the image name has a space (listed in issue #1). Does django automatically replace a space with underscore ? also, if it does that, why not save the new name with underscore in the db?? or is there some dot, that i'm failing to connect ?

Comment: `upload_to="campaign_pictures"` should be `upload_to="campaign_pictures/"`

Comment: first try to upload files which has names without space, then proceed. divide & conquer

Comment: @engin_ipek : i added '/' to upload_to="campaign_pictures/". then ran makemigrations and migrate before running the server.

upload making new entry (used testimage.jpg ).. then image got saved to pictures/campaign_pictures folder but in landing_page.html , using {{campaign.campaign_image.url }} displays pictures/testimage.jpg instead of pictures/campaign_pictures/testimage.jpg

Comment: In settings make `MEDIA_ROOT = 'pictures'`

Comment: replaced `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'pictures')` to `MEDIA_ROOT='pictures'`. still no change, the url of images is still `'pictures/testimage.jpg'` instead of `'pictures/campaign_pictures/testimage.jpg'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206197/discussion-between-irfan-harun-and-engin-ipek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed in urls.py file

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also correct it with

```
    campaign_image = models.ImageField(default="default_campaign.png",upload_to="campaign_pictures/")
```

Comment: my urls.py and campaign_image is exactly as you have mentioned. yet on doing {{campaign.campaign_image.url}}, the url of image is 'pictures/image name' instead of 'pictures/campaign_pictures/image name'

Comment: check your settings whether DEBUG = True or not.

Comment: tried with DEBUG=True and DEBUG=False. issue still persists

Comment: It seems everything is fine. Could you please add another object and try with that, may be you are trying with the object file that was created from your old settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the 'upload_to' as a callable function and use the os.path to join the directory name with the media url.

Your field will call a function which will provide the path.

```
 campaign_image = models.ImageField(default="default_campaign.png",upload_to=get_campaign_path)
```

and define your function like this

```
import os
def get_campaign_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('campaign_pictures/',filename)
```

Reference: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

Comment: i defined the function above the campaign model and updated the campaign_image field. added new data. still no change in the output. the filepath still shows 'pictures/imagename' instead of 'pictures/campaign_pictures/imagename'

does that which kind of indicates that the function `get_campaign_path` didnt work ?

Comment: can you check in your db? what gets stored in the campaign_image field?